# Furnace 3amp fuse blows when smart thermostat placed in base plate

Tags: thermostat

I am trying to switch from a Honeywell thermostat to a Ecobee smart thermostat.
I have a high efficiency York furnace only system. No A/C or humidifier. System is less than 10 years old and functions perfectly with the Honeywell.

Right now, only 2 wires are connected from the Honeywell to the furnace, the R and W terminals.

The Ecobee wants a C wire and there is a C terminal on the furnace circuit board.
I have unused wires in the thermostat wire bundle so I pick one and connect the furnace C terminal to the Ecobee base plate C terminal.

Otherwise, the furnace R terminal to Ecobee RC terminal and the furnace W terminal to Ecobee W1 terminal.

Ecobee is new out of box.

As soon as Ecobee is placed in its base plate, it blows the 3 Amp fuse on the furnace circuit board.

I am trying to figure out whether I have a bad thermostat or an issue with the C terminal on my furnace.

I live in Alaska and a functioning smart thermostat would be nice to keep an eye on the house when gone.

How do I get this wired so it works?

Comment: I had the exact opposite problem. New furnace installed with an old thermostat. Worked great for AC, then we turned the heat on and blew a fuse in the furnace. Our HVAC guy wired the furnace for a C wire, but our 'stat was set for 2-stage heat. I laughed as I watched him blow about 4 more fuses trying to figure out what was wrong before it hit him. He rewired the connection at the furnace and that fixed it. You might have the opposite problem...

Comment: I also fixed up the formatting some to match what you were after and added an actual question, which is expected around here...

Comment: I blew the fuse on my tekmar system by drawing too many VA.  You might need to add an additional transformer ( that's what I did ) or change the transformer out to provide more VA.  What is the VA requirement of the ecobee and the VA requirement of your furnace components and rating of your transformer.

Comment: I do not know the VA requirements. I do not believe it to be an overload situation as the fuse blows prior to the thermostat even powering up. It acts like a direct short in the system.

Comment: I figured out the reason the fuse is blowing. There is continuity between the furnace R terminal and it's C terminal. This is a direct short. The furnace C terminal was never used in my application so the direct short was never discovered. The question is whether I can safely use the chassis ground screw as my thermostat C terminal.

Comment: @jameskoecher what model of furnace do you have?